# How can i get all instances of class from imported model?

Tags: python, class, python-3.x, oop

Person is a new class that has two properties: `height` and `weight`.

```
class People:

    def __init__(self, height, weight):
        self.height = height
        self.weight = weight
```

I want import another `file.py` that has the same class and some objects of this class. For example:

```
p1 = People(185, 87)
p2 = People(167, 73)
p3 = People(173, 90)
```

But I don`t know how each variable called and how much variables exist in a given file. **How can i get all objects of imported file?** The goal is to create list() of objects from several files.

Comment: You can go through all variables defined in the module which are visible to other modules and check if they're `isinstance(v, People)`. This will only include variables in the module's global scope though; is that really useful?

Comment: What are you really after here? Because the problem that you're trying to solve doesn't sound like a problem you should really have.

Comment: I should compare my class instances with other by assert function, and make sure they are correct implemented. There is some kind of test program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good way to do this would be with [`inspect.getmembers`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.getmembers) by utilizing its `pred` parameter.

Firstly, you could get all user defined classes in the module with [`inspect.isclass`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.isclass) and then, create a new predicate to capture any instances that are of the class(es) you got before.

Initially, grabbing the classes is easy with `isclass` as defined in `inspect`:

```
from inspect import getmembers, isclass
# the module defining the objects
import obj

# getmembers returns list of (name, val) tuples, grab vals
clses = tuple(x[1] for x in getmembers(obj, isclass))
```

Now, `clses` is a tuple of classes:

```
print(clses) # (obj.People,)
```

*If classes are already known beforehand,* *the previous step is of course, not needed*; just create a tuple of the classes you need to find and continue with the next step.

You can then create a new predicate (a simple `lambda` would suffice) that grabs objects that are instances of any of the classes in `clses`:

```
pred = lambda x: isinstance(x, clses)
instances = getmembers(obj, pred)
```

The result now being that `instances` is populated with any name in the module `obj` that is `True` for the the `isinstance` check in `pred`:

```
print(instances)
[('p1', <obj.People at 0x7f436739ce10>),
 ('p2', <obj.People at 0x7f436739c898>),
 ('p3', <obj.People at 0x7f436739cc18>)]
```